# form imbedded in wix page disappears on click and page stays the same

Tags: html, iframe, webforms, embed, velo

I'm imbedding an infusionsoft form in a wix page. Wix automatically puts it in an iframe. This is a landing page.

If I access the form directly, by entering its url in chrome's url field, it works perfectly, meaning 1) the name and email address is transmitted to infusionsoft and 2) the page goes to the thank you page.

If I access the form via the wix page, the form simply disappears when I click the submit button, and the page stays the same.

For iframe, wix blocks (according to their help page) browser API's, `<embed>`, `<object>`, `<applet>`, other plugins, and automatic triggers like playing a video. It allows allow-same-origin (re-enables third-party site scripts/content), allow-forms (re-enables form submission), allow-popups (re-enables popups), allow-scripts (re-enables custom Javascript), allow-pointer-lock (re-enables grabbing the cursor), and allow-top-navigation (re-enables changing parent frame window.location). I added all of these to the iframe tag, and it still doesn't work.

I thought that maybe the target page is showing through the frame, and it just looks blank, but that's not happening, because the thank you page has a picture background.

The only other thing I can think of is that because I have all the attributes in the iframe tag, it's not working because they're somehow conflicting with each other. So I systematically tried various combinations, but that strategy might not be effective if there really are conflicts.

It seems like I would definitely need the attributes allow-same-origin, allow-forms and allow-top-navigation, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas? ---- I'm out of ideas.

Here's the form accessed directly using it's url. This works the way it's supposed to, by going to the thank you page. If you test it, no worries, the site's not live. Use the name "test" and the email test@test.com:
https://[id].infusionsoft.com/app/form/web-form-submitted1

Here's the wix landing page:
https://[id].wixsite.com/squeeze

Here's the HTML I entered into the code field that is used to imbed content in an iframe on a wix page:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://[id].infusionsoft.com/app/form/web-form-submitted1"     
height="175" target="https://[id].wixsite.com/squeeze/thank-you"
sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-popups  
allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden"  
frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've solved this. It turns out that I was using the wrong version of the HTML code provided by infusionsoft. A quick copy/paste fixed the problem.

Comment: The version of the HTML that worked was for the entire page, not just the form. The fact that the page was blank around the form apparently was irrelevant. The code for the whole page needed to be there.